# Twilight Zone or Outer Limits episode about a robot servant

Tags: story-identification, tv, the-twilight-zone, the-outer-limits

Don't remember which was it from, but I recall seeing an episode about a scientist who was the last survivor on Earth and designed a robot to serve him, he's a like a butler. All is good, but the master/scientist is still not happy. I don't remember the middle part, but the end was a sexy woman going into the room to serve the master, and she turned out to be the robot changing into a female body to better serve his master.

It might not even be from TZ or OL, but I'm sure it's black-and-white.

Comment: Can you remember when you watched this or anything else that happens? If so, or you want to add anything else, you can [edit] your question.

Comment: I don't remember such an episode in the Twilight Zone (but I saw that series so many years ago). There's an Outer Limits episode dealing with a female android though, titled Valerie 23. https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4cmrhc

Comment: The closest Twilight Zone episode might be "[Uncle Simon](https://imdb.com/title/tt0734687/)", S5E8, but I think @beichst's answer is a better match.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for *The Outer Limits* episode ["Bits of Love"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667866/).

> Don't remember which was it from, but I recall seeing an episode about a scientist who was the last survivor on Earth

The last man on Earth living in an underground bunker

> and designed a robot to serve him, he's a like a butler. All is good, but the master/scientist is still not happy.

has a computerized system takes care of his every need including providing holographic friends and relatives.

> I don't remember the middle part, but the end was a sexy woman going into the room to serve the master, and she turned out to be the robot changing into a female body to better serve his master.

Eventually the system, a female named Emma, demands to be loved.

> It might not even be from TZ or OL, but I'm sure it's black-and-white.

It was not in black and white when I watched it.